# why 对 and not 关于？

Tags: difference

In an Essay I wrote:

> 费先生关于「焉有稼」所说的仿佛有道理。这样的观念让上者成为了「五谷不分」的人。但他**关于**孟夫子写的略有偏见

My teacher corrected the second (bold) 关于 to 对。 Is this presumably to avoid repetition, or are there subtleties creating a preference, when used in conjunction with different verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about avoiding repetition, but the difference of 关于/对 in usage.

对…（持态度）is a collocation. It is similar to "toward" as in "attitude toward" collocation.

**他对你颇有偏见**（correct）

**他关于你颇有偏见**（incorrect）

关于 serves as "about" "with regard to"

**胡适所作关于新诗的那番论调饱受非议**（correct）（**discussion/view（derogatory）** on/about modern poetry）

**胡适对鲁迅为人的论断彰显其翩翩风度**（correct）（**judgement/conclusion** of 鲁迅's humanness）

Comment: Why does the verb after 寫 remain important? I would have thought that the relevant verb is 寫。All my investigations confirmed what you said, but nobody has been able to explain it,

Comment: @Ludi Another concern: 但他**关于**孟夫子写**得**略有偏见= But what he writes about Mencius is slightly biased≠但他**对**孟夫子写**的**略有偏见=But he is slightly biased against what Mencius writes. I hope that you may perceive the difference.ԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ)

Comment: Oh yes! Probably deserves to be added to the answer!

Answer (score -1):

since "关于" is for object not for people.
"对"is for a man not for object.